# ubuntu 14.04 LTS server / dovecot / postfix / size attachment

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I installed/configured at my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server the mailserver with Postfix and Dovecot.

I tried via Roundcube-webmail to send an email with an attachment (size 12mb). But when I click at the send button, I get the message:

```
SMTP-error: Message size exceeds server limit
```

How and where can I set this message-size-server-limit?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

Add/set `message_size_limit` in `main.cf`:

```
message_size_limit = 104857600
```

and restart Postfix.

I had to ADD it, because this line wasn't in `main.cf`